# find an object in a bindinglist by a property of the object

Tags: vb.net

I have a class inheriting bindinglist.

```
Public Class clsCustomerPurchaseOrders
    Inherits BindingList(Of clsCustomerPurchaseOrder)
```

I have some code that updates a DataGridView row with values entered by a user.  I know the id of the clsCustomerPurchaseOrder thats been changed and I know that the bindinglist has been updated with the values.

How do I search the bindingList to find the clsCustomerPurchaseOrder with the id I have, so I can return that clsCustomerPurchaseOrder object for further work?

Do I have to iterate though all the ClsCustomerPurchaseorders in the bindinglist to find the right one or is there a find/search function?

thanks!

Comment: looking at the docs, there is a find method in the interface, which means you can override and implement your own find function. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.ibindinglist.find?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_ComponentModel_IBindingList_Find_System_ComponentModel_PropertyDescriptor_System_Object_

Comment: @Jeremy, The `BindingList(Of T)` class implements the `IBindingList.Find` method explicitly, so I'm not sure that it can be overridden. There is a protected `FindCore` method though, so you could add your own method and call that internally. Both `Find` and `FindCore` take a `PropertyDescriptor` too, so not completely friendly. That said, the class does implement `IEnumerable(Of T)`, so you can always use LINQ methods like `Where`, `SingleOrDefault` or `FirstOrDefault`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney  I'll look up using LINQ, not familiar with it but thanks.

Comment: @jeremy - the example looks very much just like what I'm doing at the moment, iterating though the objects.  I was hoping there was a built in function that had property and value to match as parameters.